# how to pass two different value from form submit in asp.net mvc 5 and how to use @html.ActionLInk as asubmit Button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@model Otaidea.Models.AdvertiseVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectPackage", "SubscriptionTypes", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Hotel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServicesID, "ServicesID", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ServicesID", null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServicesID, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Service Type</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.SubscriptionTypes)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Duration)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceType)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.SubscriptionTypeID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.SubscriptionTypeID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.SubscriptionTypeID })|
                        @Ajax.ActionLink("S", "SelectPackage", new { id = item.SubscriptionTypeID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Select" class="btn btn-success'" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
```

I need when click the `@Ajax.Actionlink()` its pass the id and form value to the following method

```
public string SelectPackage(int ServicesID , int id)
```

Comment: `@Html.Actionlink()` generates a link. If you want to also pass the form values, the use `jquery.ajax` (stays on the same page) or dynamically build the query string values using javascript/jquery.

Comment: when i am clicked the actionlink button its pass the value one one its doesn't pass the other form value

Comment: Read my last comment! And which method do you also want to pass the value of `<select>` element to?

Comment: i want to pass two value first i need pass the ServiceID and then i need to pass the id = item.SubscriptionTypeID  from the ActionLInk

Comment: To which method? (`Edit`, `Details`, `Delete` or `SelectPackage`) And why do you have a form element to submit to the `SelectPackage()` method and then also want to pass the value of the `<select>` to one or more of these other elements? (its unclear what your wanting to achieve)

Comment: SelectPackage  .. actually i need the ServicesId and SubscriptionTypeID in controller how can i get this recive

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the `Html.BeginForm()` in your view?

Comment: actually i dont need but i need to transfer this value view to  controller .. how can i do this ???

Comment: Do you want to stay on the same page (and update it) or redirect to the view returned by the `SelectPackage()` method?

Comment: what do you mean by same page .? i need when a user us click a actionlink its give me the vlaue  of ServicesID and subscriptionTYpeID

Comment: You need to give more information about what your trying to do (as it is the answer would need to be 10 pages long to cover all the options). Post you controller method for the `SelectPackage()` method. And you currently show a `@Ajax.ActionLink()` to that method which would stay on the same page but its not clear what you really want to do when you click the link.

Comment: when a user click on @ajaxActionlink i need to send the value of  @Html.DropDownList("ServicesID", null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"}) serviceid and  @Ajax.ActionLink("S", "SelectPackage", new { id = item.SubscriptionTypeID } this id

Comment: I repeat. Post you controller code for the `SelectPackage()` method!

Comment: public string SelectPackage(int ServicesID , int in)
        {
            
            return "success";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view replace

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("S", "SelectPackage", new { id = item.SubscriptionTypeID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

with

```
<a href="#" class="selectpackage" data-id="@item.SubscriptionTypeID">S</a>
```

and add the following jquery script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("SelectPackage")';
$('.selectpackage').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var servicesid = $('#ServicesID').val();
  $.post(url, { ID: id, ServicesID: servicesid }, function(data) {
    // do something with the data you return
    alert(data); // alerts "success"
  });
})
```

which will post to the following method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SelectPackage(int ServicesID , int ID)
{
  .... // do something
  return Json("success");
}
```

Side note: Its not clear what the purpose of your current `Html.BeginForm()` and the submit button is or why you have `@Html.ValidationSummary()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` both of which are pointless based on the view your have shown (there is nothing to validate).

Comment: Thank Your So much .No one is happy more then me  in this world

Comment: I have edited your question, but you need to give a better explanation of what your trying to achieve in future questions :)

Comment: i am too much weak in English language thats why i cant explain in better way  . .